# How do I "deactivate" an entity instead of deleting it using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm not so sure if this is really trivial to do and I'm just over-complicating stuff, but I've been thinking about this for the good part of the past hour or so.

So I have entities. Hence, NHibernate. What I want to do is to only "deactivate" entities whenever I want to "delete" them, instead of actually removing them physically from the database. (Just cause we don't want to be really deleting records from our data store).

All my entities inherit from a `BaseEntity` class with a `BaseEntity.Active` property.

What I've got running right now is something like the following in the entity class' mapping file:

```xml
<sql-delete>
UPDATE SomeEntityTable SET Active = 0 WHERE Id = ?
</sql-delete>
```

This works fine, except that I'll have to inject that, customized with the table name, into every single HBM mapping file for every single entity (we're not implementing the `BaseEntity` inheritance in any subclassing strategy).

As you can see, that can be a bit menial. The coding would be *tedious*, the maintenance *horrendous*, and declaring the table name twice in the same mapping file just rubs me the wrong way.

What I was playing around earlier was whether or not I could implement an event listener; perhaps `OnPreDelete` or something, and update the entity's `.Active` property, like so:

```
class BaseEventListener : IPreDeleteListener
{
    public bool OnPreDelete(PreDeleteEvent @event)
    {
        BaseEntity be = @event.Entity as BaseEntity;
        if (be != null) 
            be.Active = false;

        return false;
    }
}
```

That way, the whole "deactivation" thingy is automated for all entities that support deactivation.

The problem is, I'm thinking that NHibernate would still build a proper DELETE SQL query that will burn my entity from the data store anyway instead of updating the thing, so this'll just be wasted automagic effort.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an event listener. You have to add the listener to the configuration as well.

```
public class SoftDeleteEventListener : DefaultDeleteEventListener
    {
        protected override void DeleteEntity(IEventSource session, object entity, EntityEntry entityEntry, bool isCascadeDeleteEnabled, IEntityPersister persister, ISet transientEntities)
        {
            var softDeletable = entity as BaseEntity;
            if (softDeletable != null)
            {
                softDeletable.Active = false;
            }
            else
            {
                base.DeleteEntity(session, entity, entityEntry, isCascadeDeleteEnabled, persister, transientEntities);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I also have to update that entity somehow after setting .Active? Something like session.SaveOrUpdate(softDeletable); ?

Comment: @Richard: that wouldn't be required, nhibernate would use dirty tracking to determine that an update was needed when your session was flushed.

Comment: Thanks @Paco, @DanP. I think I'll go with this, and just add explicit calls to `CascadeBeforeDelete()` and `CascadeAfterDelete()` in the soft delete conditional block.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's pretty clear that you never actually delete your persistent entities (as is the case with most applications), there's is no need to use the `Delete` method just because it's there.

An alternative approach:

- Declare a base entity with an `Active` property
- Set it to false for "delete" use cases. You can even add a `Delete` method to your base entity that does just that
- You can, additionally, [create a filter](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-filters) to avoid loading "deleted" entities

Yes, there *is* some work involved, but in the long run it's for the best, as you'll still have a maintainable, non-hacky implementation.

Some of the burden can be reduced if you use a code+convention-based  mapping approach, like ConfORM or Fluent.

Comment: While an implementation like this _definitely_ suits my palate better, I'm actually looking into modifying the actual NH delete behavior to leverage the mappings, so that the "delete" naturally cascades into the entity's relationships as well. The filter suggestion is a really great touch though, and I'm sure I'll be using that with my project. Thanks! +1

Comment: You could have your BaseEntity.Delete method do the cascade too... Each entity would specify what collections to cascade, and that's it.